# MariaDB Slave_Parallel_Mode = optimistic seems to be ignored

Tags: mariadb, replication, slave

MariaDB Master/Slave setup.

I have set 
slave_parallel_mode = optimistic
under [mysqld] section in /etc/mysql/my.cnf

The problem is that SHOW ALL SLAVES STATUS command is showing "Parallel_Mode" = "conservative". Even though I have set it to be "optimistic"

SHOW ALL SLAVES STATUS: Parallell_Mode = conservative

SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'slave_parallel_mode'   = optimistic  # this is expected, the variable is set correctly! but being ignored?

It's as if MariaDB ignores my "slave_parallel_mode" = "optimistic"

I have restarted the slave database multiple times. 
I have looked in error logs.
I can't find any reason why it's conservative when I set it to be optimistic.
I have enabled GTID on the master and slave.

I have read the documentation 100 times https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/parallel-replication/
It does not say what more is required than setting slave_parallel_mode = optimistic..

Thank you for any help :)

Let me know if you want to see values of other variables etc.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that I have named connections and slave_parallel_mode needs to be set per connection.

stop all slaves;

set global connection_name.slave_parallel_mode = 'optmistic';

start all slaves;

show all slaves status;

solved the problem for me!

Answer (score 0):

```
Flip to optimistic mode.

verify if it is optimistic mode or conservative?
show variables like '%slave_parallel_mode%';

connect to server

Stop all slaves;
Set global connection_name.slave_parallel_mode = 'optimistic';
Start all slaves;
Show all slaves status;

Now update in custom.cnf file (Slave_parallel_mode=optimistic)

Restart database
```

Comment: Please review code blocks, they are mixed with your textual response.